# Bayesian Parameter estimation (Pattern Classification by Duda, et al

Tags: self-study, pattern-recognition, integral, density-estimation

I have been trying to solve question 17 of chapter 3 (Maximum Likelihood and bayesian estimation) of the book "Pattern Classification" by Duda, et al.

The question goes as follows:

[image]

[image]

Now the part (a) is quite clear and obvious. But I am stuck doing the part (b).

The solution that has been provided is as follows:

[image]

In P(D) computation I'm not able to figure out how the integral has been solved. I'm not too good with integrals so I'm assuming that I'm missing some property or intuition here.

Any kind of intuition on this or some reference will be quite helpful here

Comment: Please may you clarify which part of the integral you are unable to understand?

Comment: The last two steps essentially. I've understood the formulation of the integral but I'm not able to understand how it is  expanded to d integrals in the second step.